# Why do routers have an IP Address if computers already have a network portion in their IP?

Tags: networking, ip, protocols, router

That's essentially my question. Isn't the network portion in a computer's IP address so that, when it is sent, other computers can look at that network portion and know where to send it back to? So why do routers have their own IP address?

Comment: Routers need to communicate with other routers to exchange routes. From this perspective, they are peer hosts. I fail to see what this has to do with programming, and I think it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The router needs to be a node on the same network as the computer using it.  When your PC tries to communicate with a system on a different network, it consults it's routing table to figure out which router (there can be several) has the route to the destination.  Without an IP on the router, there would be no way to send packets to the router, and thus no way to get out of your network.

I suppose the IP protocol could have been designed to use broadcasts to find the route out, but that would have caused issues with traffic congestion.  Thankfully it wasn't designed like that.